# find columns with same multivalue attributes

Tags: mysql

```
+------------+---------------+
| BR_NAME    | FACILITIES    |
+------------+---------------+
| headoffice | fixeddeposit  |
| headoffice | locker        |
| headoffice | mobilebanking |
| headoffice | netbanking    |
| zone1      | fixeddeposit  |
| zone1      | mobilebanking |
| zone1      | netbanking    |
| zone2      | fixeddeposit  |
| zone2      | netbanking    |
| zone3      | fixeddeposit  |
| zone3      | locker        |
| zone3      | netbanking    |
| zone4      | netbanking    |
| zone5      | locker        |
| zone6      | fixeddeposit  |
| zone6      | locker        |
| zone7      | locker        |
| zone7      | mobilebanking |
| zone8      | locker        |
| zone8      | mobilebanking |
| zone9      | locker        |
+------------+---------------+
```

This is my database i want to find br_name with same multivalue attributes ex: zone7 ,zone8 how to query it using mysql

Comment: So, start doing it and when you have tried yourself, THEN get back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using `group_concat` ([also please see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79de3/2/0))

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt (BR_NAME VARCHAR(50),ALLFACILITIES VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO tt
(SELECT
    BR_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(FACILITIES)
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY FACILITIES) as t1
GROUP BY
    BR_NAME);

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(BR_NAME) AS BR_NAMES,
  ALLFACILITIES
FROM
  tt
GROUP BY
  ALLFACILITIES
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
BR_NAMES        ALLFACILITIES

zone9,zone5     locker
zone7,zone8     mobilebanking,locker
```

Note that you can remove `COUNT(*) > 1` and get the facilities of every BR_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using group by and having.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName group by BR_NAME having count(*) >= 2
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) c FROM TableName GROUP BY BR_NAME HAVING c > 1;
```

Comment: the result should be zone 7 and zone 8 cause they have same facilities not same count

Comment: @perpetual i see that `zone6` and `zone2` also has same count.

Comment: TRUE that,how do i write a query for that?

Comment: @perpetual so just use `having count(*) = 2`